# Manage Click events through overlapping items

Tags: jquery, events, slideshow, overlapping

I got a javascript overlapping problem in a slideshow component. I want to add a icon to delete a picture in the slideshow, this icon is on the right top corner of each picture.

The problem is : The icon (and his click event) is under a big blank div (in blue on the screenshot). This div is used to go to the next picture.

Is there a solution to fire the icon event & block the slideshow event?

[image]

Comment: Can we can get some code?

Comment: `<div id="slideshowController1" class="slideshowController" style="pointer-events: none;"></div>

<div id="slideshowController2" class="slideshowController" style="pointer-events: none;"></div>

<div id="mySwipe" class="swipe" style="visibility: visible;">

<div class="swipe-wrap" id="swipe-gallery" style="width: 2500px;">

<div id="pic1">
<div id="delete1" class="thumbDelete">
<img src="../../img/delete.png" width="100%">
</div>              
</div> 

</div>`

Comment: Can't you just change the z-index of the icon, or icon container, so it renders above the blue div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the clean code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #slideshowController1
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            top: 0;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 98;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        #slideshowController2
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 98;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }

        #pic1
        {
            height: 400px;
            width: 400px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        #delete1
        {
            float: right;
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .swipe
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            visibility: hidden;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .swipe-wrap
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        #slideShow
        {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slideShow">

        <div id="slideshowController1" class="slideshowController" onclick="alert('right');">
        </div>
        <div id="slideshowController2" class="slideshowController" onclick="alert('left');">
        </div>
        <div id="mySwipe" class="swipe" style="visibility: visible;">
            <div class="swipe-wrap" id="swipe-gallery" style="width: 2500px;">
                <div id="pic1">
                    <div id="delete1" class="thumbDelete" style="z-index: 100;" onclick="alert('delete');">
                        <img src="../../img/delete.png" width="100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

if I put z-index:100 on mySwipe, it's work but only out side of the picture...
its a partial solution !

But this is not the desired operation, only the icon must be over...

Any ideas ?